# Setting dbt date variable

Tags: dbt

I am trying to set a date variable within a dbt model to be the date 7 days ago. The model will run against a Redshift database. I have done the following to set the variable, however I get the error DATE_ADD is not defined:

`{%- set start_date = TRUNC(DATE_ADD(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE)) -%}`

What is the correct way to set the variable.

Answer (score 4):

jinja is a templating language. When you run dbt, it first executes the jinja to "compile" your model, and *then* it executes your compiled code against your database.

jinja doesn't have functions called `trunc` or `date_add` or `current_date`, since those are SQL functions.

You have two choices:

1. Set the variable equal to a **string** and include that **string** in your model code, so that the database calculates this date. That would look like this (note the extra quotes):

   ```sql
   {%- set start_date = "TRUNC(DATE_ADD(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE))" -%}
   select {{ start_date }}
   ```

   If you compile this and check the code generated in your `target` directory, you'll see it becomes this SQL:

   ```sql
   select TRUNC(DATE_ADD(day, -7, CURRENT_DATE))
   ```
2. Use jinja's context to calculate the date and include the date literal in your SQL. dbt's jinja context includes a special variable called [`run_started_at`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_started_at), and also Python's [`datetime` module](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/modules). Putting those together looks like this:

   ```sql
   {%- set start_datetime = run_started_at - modules.datetime.timedelta(days=7) -%}
   {%- set start_date = start_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") -%}
   select '{{ start_date }}'
   ```

   This will compile to:

   ```sql
   select '2023-01-12'
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Both of the above methods worked. I went with #1.