# DBT jinja code for Generating current date

Tags: jinja2, dbt, dbt-cloud

Before job runs everyday, I trying to create a partition_key variable = currentdate()-1 so that my pipeline would run for previous day but I am getting errors within DBT console

> No filter named 'format_datetime'.
> line 2
> set partition_key = dateadd('day', -1, CURRENT_DATE())|format_datetime('%Y-%m-%d') %}

Code I am using in the DBT :

```
{% macro yesterday_date() %}
{% set partition_key = dateadd('day', -1, CURRENT_DATE())|format_datetime('%Y-%m-%d') %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Also, tried to set Partition_key within my sql file but still it gave me the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting dbt date variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175545/setting-dbt-date-variable)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you already found a way to solve your problem as this question was posted 6 months ago, but I'll answer it in case someone else needs it.

[Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) is a templating language that uses some syntax from Python and where you cannot use your well-known SQL functions. To be able to get a date string for yesterday in Jinja, you need to write:

```
{% macro yesterday_date() %}
  {% set partition_key = (modules.datetime.datetime.now() - modules.datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the current date with either of these methods in your jinja template:

**Using the DBT run_started_at variable:**

```
{{run_started_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}
```

**Using the datetime package:**

```
{{modules.datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}
```

Or if you're looking to do something more complicated, you could look into a package such as

> dbt-date
> https://github.com/calogica/dbt-date